# Prestashop Search API Method in IOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, api, search, prestashop

I'm building my first IOS Application and I'm currently integrating my application with my Prestashop website.  I already have grabbed a ton of data from the databases, but I'm having less luck using the Search Method from their API.

I have successfully called the REST API and authenticated with the server.  I'm getting back a response status code of 200 so everything looks ok with the authentication, however the data I'm receiving from the server is the homepage of my site in HTML form rather than an XML file with the search results.

Below I'll list some of the parts of code in question that I'm using to access the Prestashop server

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.******.com:443/api/search/?query=%@&language=1",searchTerm]];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
```

This is the method I use to set up the connection to the Prestashop Server

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"Test 1.5");
    [self clearCookiesForURL];
    if([challenge previousFailureCount]==0)
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"(I'm omitting the credential key but it does work)" password:@"" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"Credential : %@",credential);
        //NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];

        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else{
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

And this is the method for my authentication.  I have all of the other connection methods instantiated (canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace, didReceiveResponse, didReceiveData, etc.) and they are all being called and working fine.

```
NSLog(@"Data After : %@",responseData);
NSString *tempString;
tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"String : %@",tempString);
```

This is the section of code I use to translate the data I get from the server into a string (which i thought was going to be XML but is instead HTML)

[Here is a screenshot of the debug log showing that I'm getting an HTML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IYoC.jpg)

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!